# I have a textbox and button. I want to show alert with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a textbox and button. I want to show an `alert` when I click the button. But I have a condition; the innput text value must be `X1`. If user write `X1` in to textbox, show an alert `GOOD` otherwise alert `NOT GOOD`.

How can I do that with using jQuery? Here are my html codes.

```
<input type="text" id="couponInput" class="couponInput" placeholder="Input Code" />                                                       
<button type="button" id="couponApply" class="couponApply">APPLY</button>
```

Comment: This reads like a brief. Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself?

Comment: Just read the doc: here are some methods you should need `val` `click`. Take a look at selectors also : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You're right. I am new on JQuery, of course I made some attempts but they don't work.

Comment: This is so basic i cannot believe you didn't find anything on the WEB to solve your expected behaviour. Do some serach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want specific jquery answer. Here it is ....

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // Document ready event -- most important

    $('#couponApply').click(function(event){

        var couponInputval = $('#couponInput').val(); // Getting the input value
        couponInputval = couponInputval.toUpperCase(); // Changing to upper case
        if(couponInputval == 'X1') {
            alert("GOOD");
        }
        else{
            alert("NOT GOOD");
        }
        event.preventDefault(); // To restrict button to push request to the server

    });


});
```

Hope it helps ......

Answer (score 0):

Add this javascript

```
//This detect the onClick event on your button
$("#couponApply").click(function(){
//here you retrieve the value of your input
var inputValue = $("#couponInput").val();
//And now, you test it
if(inputValue == "X1")
    alert("GOOD");
else
    alert("NotGOOD");
});
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbb3p11a/2/)

Answer (score -3):

You don't need jQuery for that, but try this

```
<button type="button" id="couponApply" class="couponApply" onclick="if($('#couponInput').val() == 'X1'){alert('GOOD');} else {alert('NOT GOOD');}">APPLY</button>
```

Also if you are trying to verify coupons than this is not a good way to do that - your code will be easy to read in source of your website - you should do it on the server side

Comment: That's bad advice to use inline scripting and anyway you are using jQuery here...

Comment: @berry my answer is not the best one, but it is easy to implement. just try to use the $('#couponApply').click() in the future.